# MySQL Date without seconds

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I have searched around for an answer to my question and it seems the DATE_FORMAT function should allow me to remove the seconds - I need to format a column from my table and the results go into a drop-down box - I have the following code;

```
$DepartSailing = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SailingTime,'%h:%i %p') AS FormattedTime FROM wp_timetable WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<select name='adults' id='adults' style='width: 300px; height: 30px; padding: 5px;'>";
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($DepartSailing)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['SailingTime'] ."'>" . $row['SailingTime'] ."</option>";}
echo "</select>";
```

The statement works if I just take out the DATE_FORMAT function. But it displays the seconds - can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: The query should work fine. The problem is probably in how you're accessing the results.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` works the same with a table column as it does with `NOW()`.

Comment: How are you accessing the result column when you haven't given an alias to it?

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your response. I have added in an alias and my corresponding code - any suggested changes to make this work?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Since you're using an alias `AS FormattedTime` then change  `$row['SailingTime']` to `$row['FormattedTime']` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working now - I wasn't sure about alias's hopefully this can help someone else who isnt sure about them either :) Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome Sarah, *cheers!* I guess I should put in an answer if you want others to benefit from it. Otherwise, you can delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an alias `AS FormattedTime`

You will need to change `$row['SailingTime']` to `$row['FormattedTime']`

Here is a tutorial on aliases:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Here is an example that was pulled from that page:

```
SELECT [col1 | expression] AS `descriptive name`
FROM table_name
```

You're also using a deprecated MySQL API which will be removed from future PHP releases.

- You should consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.